# checking whether spring boot application is running or not

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment, scripting

I've created a spring boot project and deployed it on a vm. I've added a command in local.rc that starts the spring boot application on reboot. I want to check whether the command got executed and the application is running. How do I do that?

Comment: `ps -fe | grep java` or something

Comment: If you find any of the provided answers useful, please [mark it as "accepted"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways

1. On system level - you can run your project as a service, which is documented in the [Official documentation - Deployments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service). Then you can query the application status `service myapp status`.
2. On application level - include Spring Boot Actuator in your app and use the Actuator endpoints such as `/actuator/health` as per [Official documentation - Production Ready Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html). These endpoints can be exposed via [HTTP or JMX](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints).

*Note: prior to spring boot 2.0 the actuator endpoint is `/health`*

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web project, it makes sense to include spring-boot-actuator (just add a dependency in maven and start the microservice).

In this case, it will automatically expose the following endpoint (for example, its actually can be flexibly set up):

```
http://<HOST>:<PORT>/health
```

Just issue an HTTP GET request, and if you get 200 - it's up and running.

If using an actuator is not an option (although it should be really addressed as a first bet), then you can merely telnet to `http://<HOST>:<PORT>`

The ratio behind this is that that PORT is exposed and ready to "listen" to external connections only after the application context is really started.